# ExtJs getTotalCount() not returning the number of records in the store

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

When I invoke a function from controller that loads data in the store in the following manner,

```
var store= new Ext.getStore('MyStore');
store.load();
```

The response header shows that the following JSON data is returned,

```
{"usrdata":[{"name":"John",
             "roll":"5",
             "address":"abcd"
           }]
}
```

but the problem is when I write

```
console.log(store.getTotalCount());
```

it shows '0' (zero) on the console.

Can somebody please help me identify why is it not showing the actual count of the number of records in the store.

I feel it might be because store has not finished loading when the function is invoked (may be I am not correct).

following is the code of my store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',

    timeout : 60000,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create: 'php/insert.php', 
            read: 'php/read.php',
            update: 'php/update.php',
            destroy: 'php/delete.php',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'usrdata',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            root: 'usrdata'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
});
```

Comment: this is most probable reason _I feel it might be because store has not finished loading when the function is invoked_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a tiny change in your store definition

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',

    timeout : 60000,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create: 'php/insert.php', 
            read: 'php/read.php',
            update: 'php/update.php',
            destroy: 'php/delete.php',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'usrdata',
            totalProperty : '<the_node_of_json_response_which_holds_the_count>'
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            root: 'usrdata'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true,
});
```

PS - your service needs to return the count. getTotalCount() does not return how many records your store contains, it returns the number that the totalProperty of reader object holds.

So if your service is returning the data -

```js
{
    "total": 122,
    "offset": 0,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "ed-spencer-1",
            "value": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ed Spencer",
                "email": "ed@sencha.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

your reader object would look like -

```js
 reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'usrdata',
                totalProperty : 'total'
                successProperty: 'success'
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback in the load method to get the record count: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

```
store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // the operation object
        // contains all of the details of the load operation
        console.log(records.length);
        // Alternative
        console.log(store.getTotalCount());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case we are solving the wrong problem. Usually you would want a total counter to be always returned from the server along your data, this way pagination etc will all work automatically. See [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json) for examples:

```
{
    "total": 122,
    "offset": 0,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "ed-spencer-1",
            "value": 1,
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Ed Spencer",
                "email": "ed@sencha.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```